# Is it possible to turn two select statements into one without UNION ALL/UNION when the only difference are two lines?

Tags: sql

If you have 2 `SELECT` queries that are exactly alike but the only difference is that one query has `3 INNER JOINS` while another has `2 INNER JOINS` and one of them has only 1 additional `WHERE` criteria, is it possible to combine them into one `SELECT` statement without using `UNION ALL/UNION` when you want results from both?

Example query 1:

```
    SELECT a.id, a.name, b.type
    FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b on a.id = b.a_id
    WHERE
    a.lang < '20'
```

Example query 2a:

```
    SELECT a.id, a.name, b.type
    FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b on a.id = b.a_id
    INNER JOIN TableC c on a.id = c.a_id
    WHERE
    a.id < '20'
    c.lang = 'French'
```

What about if the query has 3 differences?

Example query 2b:

```
    SELECT a.id, a.name, b.type
    FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b on a.id = b.a_id
    INNER JOIN TableC c on a.id = c.a_id
    WHERE
    a.id < '20'
    a.year = '2020'
    c.lang = 'French'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example; the latter is a subset of the former.  Which do you want to return?

Comment: I would like the results to be the same as if I used the keyword UNION to combine example query 1 and 2a or example query 1 and 2b

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.type
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b on a.id = b.a_id
LEFT JOIN TableC c on a.id = c.a_id and c.lang = 'French'
WHERE
a.id < '20'
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe the only different between your two queries is that the first doesn't require `c.lang = 'French'`, but the second query does... in this example, isn't the first query a super set of the second query, only with fewer duplicates?

If this is only true because it's a simplified example, the following query should handle this type of situation...

---

EDIT: I just noticed the 3rd query example in your post... basically, anything that limits the second query beyond the first query would need to be added to the `LEFT JOIN` clause, and not to the `WHERE` clause...

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.type
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b on a.id = b.a_id
LEFT JOIN TableC c on a.id = c.a_id AND c.lang = 'French' AND a.year = '2020'
WHERE a.id < '20'
```

Comment: The First query is somewhat a super set.  But Query 1 displays 3, London, Island ; 5, Dublin, Island; and Oslo, Inland while Query 2 displays just 4, Paris, Inland.  I was just curious if it was possible to retrieve all four cities as a result without having to use UNION or UNION ALL.

Comment: Does the query with the `LEFT JOIN` display the desired results?

Comment: Not really, there are a few rows missing from the final result